# InconsistentMigrationHistory with django user_auth

Tags: django, authentication, user-accounts

I'm working on my first django project and I'm trying to add `user_authentication` now. I know i probably should've done this at the very start but I'm trying to do it now. I have a few other apps created and its running fine. However when I added an accounts app i get the following error when i run migrations in accounts/models.py

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with migrations in situation where I have problem like:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydjango.MyApp_publication' doesn't exist").

It's regarded to the connections.py is following:

1. Run the command python manage.py
2. migrate --fake MyApp zero
3. and then python manage.py migrate MyApp.

Here 'MyApp' is the app you're creating on your Django Server.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

I delete all tables except ‘auth_user’, and run ‘python manage.py makemigrations myapp’ ‘python manage.py migrate myapp’ again.

This solved the problem.